# Rails | Handling Users / Admin / Call Center Panel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, admin

I have a rails app and within I have User model. I added `admin:boolean` column to user table and `:default => false`.

Now I would like to create a call center panel on the system to be able to handle user requests by phone etc. I am wondering should I create another table like user or is it ok to add a boolean field to user table.

I know I can handle it with adding column. I will add a namespace as call_center to controller, routes etc. but my question is, which option is the most effective and sustainable one?

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen this handled is exactly as you describe, with a boolean (is admin true) or with a number in cases where there are more than two user types. Wordpress, forum software, Mediawiki, etc. need to allow for several user types which have varying degrees of access.

This is typically done the way you've done it, by adding a column to the user table that holds this number. For example, admins could be 0, moderators 1, regular users 2, etc. The number doesn't matter as long as your system makes sense to you. With your boolean, you can easily check to see if a user is an admin or not, and thus enable the admin to do things other users cannot. In doing so, you simply have to set this column up so the default is false, so when new users sign up they are not put in as admins. In short, I don't think you need another table.

Comment: Another consideration, once you get this implemented, is going to be how to make people admins. You can always do it manually in the database, but opening this up to being able to do in the backend means you then have to consider who can make someone an admin (can your other admins make other admins?). This is essentially one of the reasons why there is sometimes a superadmin vs regular admins.